# Google Big Query : How to get the authorization to change the authorizations on Data Sets

Tags: permissions, google-bigquery, dataset, permission-denied

I would like to add a member (xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com) in the list of members that are allowed to read the tables in a data set.

However, when in the Big Query console, when I click on SHARE DATASET , I have the message : 
**"You don't have permission to edit the permissions of the selected resource "****

However, I have the permission to use the query editor and to run queries on this Data Set. 
How can I add a member to the list of members who can read this DATA SET so that to access to this Data Set through a Virtual Machine ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#required_permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are receiving is because you do not have the required permissions associated with your account to share a Dataset with another member.

In order to do this, you(if possible), or an admin of the project, i.e., someone with project editor or project owner role assigned. Will need to assign the needed permissions to allow you to share datasets.

You can see all the available permissions in this document [Predefined roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#transitioning_from_primitive)

For a comprehensive document dealing with controlling access to Datasets review this document [Controlling access to datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls)

As long as you have the appropriate roles/permissions you should have no problems sharing BigQuery Datasets

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I will create another dataset and program a  query on Bigquery to copy every day a very small part of the data from the firts dataset to the second one where I can give a virtual machine all the rights to read or write.